# Java XSLT processing throws TransformerConfigurationException when run on another machine

Tags: xslt, java-8, java-7, java

I am running a Java application which is supposed to do some XSLT processing based on `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`. I developed it on an older notebook using `java-7-openjdk-amd64`.
When I run it on another machine with `java-8-openjdk-amd64` installed the Transformer throws the following exception:

> javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Failed to
>   compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
>
> XPST0017: XPath syntax error [...]
>       Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named   {http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java}java.text.SimpleDateFormat.new()
>       at net.sf.saxon.PreparedStylesheet.prepare(PreparedStylesheet.java:176)
>       at net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:139)
>       at net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:91)

The xsl file looks like this (leaving out unimportant details):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" exclude-result-prefixes="java">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>

      <body>
        <h1>Test Report</h1>
        <h2>Test run</a> at         
          [<xsl:value-of
            select="java:format(java:java.text.SimpleDateFormat.new('dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss'), java:java.util.Date.new())" />]
        </h2>
```

So the Transformer obviously has a problem with invoking `SimpleDateFormat`, but why? I could not find any information about this in respect to Java7 vs. Java8. I even copied the Jar file compiled with Jdk7 an and ran it on the other machine. Same problem, so it seems to be a runtime issue.
There are some Q+A on SO about java and XSLT but nothing turned out to be useful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out be that this declaration `<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"` does not ensure that XSLT v2.0 is actually used. `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` "secretly" used XSLT v1.0 on the old machine (with `java-7-openjdk-amd64`) and XSLT v2.0 with Saxon v9.1.0 on the other machine (with `java-8-openjdk-amd64`).

The dependency was set by a maven pom.xml at compile time. But apparently this had no effect when running it with Jre7. I could have noticed it by looking at the stack trace (`net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl`) but since there were no errors before, I was not aware of any specific TransformerFactory implementation.